# Should I replace an old furnace with a mini split unit?

Tags: hvac, heating, furnace, cooling, mini-split

I have a very small house that is close to being 700 ft.². I live in the middle of Illinois some winters it gets really cold , many degrees below zero. Last winter I noticed my furnace having a bad grinding noise in the blower motor area. I did some research and figured out that I would need to buy a whole new blower motor housing which would be somewhere around $350. It is already a very old furnace approximately 25 years old. I wouldn’t want to keep putting money into a furnace that is so this old just to have a break down again somewhere else. I thought about replacing the furnace. It is in a very tight area. I have never replaced a furnace before and I know if I hire someone to do it will cost me a fortune. My home is cooled with window air conditioners, so I think the mini split option is definitely something I could consider, at this point I price the mini split out be a little over $1000. I could install it myself in a couple of days I was planning on getting a 12,000 BTU mini split for my 700 square-foot house.

Should I invest in a mini split or keep repairing my furnace or buy a new furnace and try to replace it myself?

Comment: Need to check that a mini split will work at those temps without resistance(electrical toaster) heating(usually high cost heating).  Some might, but quite a few don't.

Comment: How many degrees below zero? Vague does not help. What is your furnace fuel source, and how many units of that fuel do you use in the coldest month?

Comment: Urbana is sort of central and has records of -25, most recently in 1999. Normals are considerably milder.

Answer (score 3):

I have doubts about the likely heating performance of a $1000 DIY minisplit, but you haven't specified which. Some crap out at +10°F, some work to -15 or even lower now. Really bad ones don't work below or even to freezing, just like olde whole house ones.

Based on USDA zone maps it's not colder than where I live (-20 in memory, -16 in last year, neither for long) which a good high-performance cold weather air to air rated to -15F operation has worked fine in (it managed -16; it managed -15 earlier; and it has never seen -20. There are defrost heaters but no auxiliary heat.)

I heat 2000 square feet with 2 12K BTU units, but I'm very well insulated. I doubt your 700 square feet is insulated all that well, just from the sort of things that were standard in a building old enough to have a 25 year old furnace in it.

If you addressed your insulation you might expect a 12K to heat it; if you don't, it might be very inadequate. We can assess that roughly by looking at your past fuel use on your existing furnace and making some assumptions about its likely efficiency.

Comment: The cheapest DIY mini splits are kind of junky, and most people don't realize how much other stuff it takes to install one.

Comment: I think a good mini-split with some resistive aux heating strips would be the way to go.  With the right unit, the aux heat may never be needed.  This assume the wiring/main panel can handle toe aux heat load.